# Self-contradictory asumption of normality? Nonparametric point-biseral correltion coeffiicent? t-test or Mann-Whitney U?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, nonparametric, pearson-r, spearman-rho

**A.** I know from the net that for a design with one binary variable and a second variable that is continuous but is **NOT normally** distributed, I can use **BOTH** the point-biserial correlation (which is basically the **parametric** Pearson correlation formula) as well as the Rank Biserial Correlation (which is equal to the **nonparametric** Spearman or Kendall τ correlations).

**B.** I also have read about linear and monotonic correlations, which implies that even the Pearson coefficient (and of course, point-biserial) is OK for **nonnormal** distributions.

**C.** And I understand that with one binary variable and a continuous one, it might even be better to use an independent-samples comparison test (e.g., unpaired t or Mann-Whitney U) instead of a correlation coefficient.

**D.** I know that the Mann-Whitney test will yield the same p-value as the Spearman coefficient, while the t-test will give the same p-value as the Pearson coefficient (and point-biserial).

**E.** I know when the groups are not large enough AND when the error terms are not normally distributed, I should use the nonparametric Mann-Whitney instead of t-test.

**Two Questions**:

The above assumptions cause some inconsistencies and confusion in the following case:

I am analyzing this design with 2 groups of 20 patients each; the independent variable is Treatment (the treatments A or B) and the dependent variable is the continuous Length measured in each group. **The latter is NOT normal** (the groups and **the error terms are all NON-normal**).

The problem is that in this particular design, the nonparametric Spearman and **Mann-Whitney** tests yield a statistically significant p-value, while the parametric point-biserial [Pearson] and **t-test** yield a quite non-significant p-value > 0.1.

**Question 1**. Which one should I use? The nonparametric Spearman / Mann-Whitney? Or the parametric point-biserial [Pearson] / t-test? On the one hand, the assumption **E** dictates that I must use the nonparametric Mann-Whitney. On the other hand, the assumptions **A and B** allow me to use the parametric point-biserial [which is actually Pearson] correlation **and by extension the t-test**. So what should I use?

**Question 2**. The assumption **E** seems to be in total conflict with the assumptions **A and B**: The results of Spearman / Mann-Whitney are identical, and so are the results of the point-biserial [Pearson] / t-test. So if I am allowed to use the point-biserial [Pearson] in the absence of normality (assumptions A and B), **why not the t-test which gives the EXACT SAME result as point-biserial**?

Comment: "*I also have read about linear and monotonic correlations, which implies that even the Pearson coefficient (and of course, point-biserial) is OK for nonnormal distributions*" -- sure, if you're measuring *linear* correlation, that doesn't necessarily require you to have normality. Normality can come into testing it but you can use tests that don't assume normality (and the usual test for a null of zero correlation is fairly robust to the usual assumption in any case). Beware, however - a lot of texts seem to get the assumption wrong (you can derive it under two distinct sets of assumptions).

Comment: To address another of your premises: "*I know when the groups are not large enough AND when the error terms are not normally distributed, I should use the nonparametric Mann-Whitney instead of t-test.*" -- I am not at all convinced that the word "*should*" belongs in that sentence. It depends. Indeed I don't think I'd agree with the general intent there either. It depends.

Comment: "Beware, however - a lot of texts seem to get the assumption wrong" Thanks for the clarifying comment and the heads up. ---- I can't claim that I understood your second comment completely.

Comment: This imperative: "*when the groups are not large enough AND when the error terms are not normally distributed, I should use the nonparametric Mann-Whitney instead of t-test*" seems to be based on a misunderstanding. I disagree with it as stated. However, it requires a longish discussion to unpack all the mistaken premises in it, well beyond a comment. Some relevant answers are on site already, though. This sort of mistaken idea probably comes from the same source as the issue discussed in my first comment - authors who make one such error typically misunderstand a host of other things.